# Можно ли заменить бесконечный цикл while на обычный

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, while

Пытаюсь заменить бесконечный цикл на обычный, но не выходит.

```
N = 5000
a = 10000000000000000000
b = 99999999999999999999
lst = []

while len(lst) < N:
    arr = [str(randint(a, b))[g:(g+4):] for g in range (0 , 20 , 5)]
    print(arr)
```

Я создал лист, в котором `N(=5000)` **`20`** разрядные числа. 
Эти числа надо разделить на `4-4` группы.

Заменить, но без использования `break` и `continue`.

Также можно заменить на цикл `for`, но и это у меня не выходит.

Comment: Во- первых, этот код не запускается. Во-вторых, неплохо бы рассказать, что вообще этот код должен делать.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1341057

Comment: Код работает, и я описал что он делает Эникейщик

Comment: У вас `lst` внутри цикла никак не используется. Туда `arr` должен добавляться или что должно быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вообще никак `lst` внутри цикла не меняется, получается, что цикл будет действительно бесконечным. Предположу, что в `lst` должен добавляться `arr` на каждой итерации цикла, т.е. цикл идёт пока в `lst` не будет `N` элементов. Тогда заменить на `for` очень просто:

```
from random import randint

N = 5000
a = 10000000000000000000
b = 99999999999999999999
lst = []

for _ in range(N):
    arr = [str(randint(a, b))[g:(g+4):] for g in range (0 , 20 , 5)]
    #print(arr)
    lst.append(arr)
```

Печать я закомментировал, чтобы экран не забивался кучей информации.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Цикл идет от листа до N, поэтому указываем это в нашем `range`:

```
for i in range(len(lst,N,1):
    arr = [str(randint(a, b))[g:(g+4):] for g in range (0 , 20 , 5)]
    print(arr)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `len` может содержать только 1 аргумент . а у вас их 3 , поэтому у меня код не работает

Comment: @ГеоргийДжобава там не хватает скобки, можно и догадаться

Comment: Знаю что там нет скобки, при добавлении скобки все равно будет ошибка. Конечно можно заключить `lst,N,1` в квадратные скобки , но тогда терминал выдаст всего 3 ответа